# Pasting the flipped pose on my armature causes distortions

Tags: rigging, armature

I've got a problem with pasting the flipped pose on my armature of a human, essential for a walk cycle. I've tried some stuff to fix it... But it keeps not working. Every time I copy the initial pose and try to paste flipped pose, it just goes all wonky and I just can't sort it out. Could anyone help me?

[image: problem with pose in rig]